# Pandas - Groupby - capture first value of a column - Wrong ouput

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe :

```
    DOCUMENT_LEDGER_ID  ACTUAL_START_DATE
        376878              2017-02-01
        376880              2017-02-01
        16043792            2017-01-05
        16043792            2017-02-04
```

I want to group it on the `DOCUMENT_LEDGER_ID` and want the first value of `ACTUAL_START_DATE`
That is my expected output :

```
Id          ACTUAL_START_DATE   
376878          2017-02-01        
376880          2017-02-01        
16043792        2017-01-05
```

I have tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
dictToAgg = {}
dictToAgg["ACTUAL_START_DATE"] = "first"
cycleTimeFilteringUnique = cycleTimeFiltering.groupby('DOCUMENT_LEDGER_ID', as_index=False).first()
```

The output I am getting is this :

```
      Id            ACTUAL_START_DATE   
    376878          2017-02-01        
    376880          2017-02-01        
    16043792        2017-02-04
```

I have seen similar questions, but am unable to understand the mistake I am committing.

Comment: For me it working nice...

Comment: Why are you sorting values? That's throwing everything out of whack.

Comment: What about alternative solution? `cycleTimeFilteringUnique = cycleTimeFiltering.sort_values(["DOCUMENT_LEDGER_ID", "ACTUAL_START_DATE"]).drop_duplicates('DOCUMENT_LEDGER_ID')` ?

Comment: @jezrael - Ya, this is working perfectly fine :) Thanks. But, still not sure why the previous is not working, will try to update my pandas version, if its working fine for you.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Because I want the first date that Id is encountered.

Comment: @Tarun - sort values do nothing, so need `cycleTimeFiltering.sort_values(["DOCUMENT_LEDGER_ID", "ACTUAL_START_DATE"], inplace=True)` or assign output.

Comment: @jezrael - That sorts the dataframe which I have, since there the dataframe is not sorted on dates and id, the example I had shown is a very small subset. But, ya, should remove it from here since I have shown a sorted dataframe

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Was the sort_values doing something its not supposed to do? As in is it not sorting based on Id and Then Start date? If So, that may be a mistake I was doing?

Comment: In your original df, for `16043792`, `2017-01-05` comes first. If you sort it, `2017-01-04` comes first. What do you want?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Ya, that's 2017-02-04, so that should come later right? I want to sort each ID based on Start date

Comment: See your expected output, it's completely opposite to what you're saying.

Comment: no, may be we are getting confused because i didnot mention the date format.. its yyyy-mm-dd. My bad.. apologies :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need assign output of `sort_values` and then aggregate `first`:

```
cols = ["DOCUMENT_LEDGER_ID", "ACTUAL_START_DATE"]
cycleTimeFilteringUnique = (cycleTimeFiltering.sort_values(cols)
                                              .groupby('DOCUMENT_LEDGER_ID', as_index=False)
                                              .first())
```

Some alternative solutions:

```
idx = cycleTimeFiltering.groupby("DOCUMENT_LEDGER_ID")['ACTUAL_START_DATE'].idxmin()
cycleTimeFilteringUnique = cycleTimeFiltering.loc[idx]
```

---

```
cols = ["DOCUMENT_LEDGER_ID", "ACTUAL_START_DATE"]
cycleTimeFilteringUnique = (cycleTimeFiltering.sort_values(cols)
                                              .drop_duplicates('DOCUMENT_LEDGER_ID'))
```

---

```
print (cycleTimeFilteringUnique)
   DOCUMENT_LEDGER_ID ACTUAL_START_DATE
0              376878        2017-02-01
1              376880        2017-02-01
2            16043792        2017-01-05
```